# Is there an equivalent of LocalEndpoint for System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket class?

Tags: c#, websocket

I am creating a WebSocket client connection using `System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket`:

```
private System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket _webSocket;
private string _uri = "ws://address";

using (System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket = new System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket())
{                        
    _webSocket = clientWebSocket;       
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ConnectTimeoutSec));

    await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(_uri, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
```

Is it possible to obtain the local endpoint including the OS-chosen ephemeral port?

With `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` there was `RemoteEndPoint` and `LocalEndPoint` with this information - and this was easily available from the `Client` property of the `TcpClient` class, for example.

Is there an equivalent for the `WebSockets.WebSocket` class and how to get to it, if so?

Comment: There is none, as far as I know. Probably developers of this class didn't see much reason to reveal this low-level information.

Comment: Would be nice for hashing into a dictionary. The web socket class just uses the basic get hash code function.